# Register user and authenticate request on server using facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, ember.js, devise

I have an app that uses ember `simple-auth` with `torii` and `devise` extensions.
My backend is on `rails` with `devise` to protect ressources. (BTW, I am a rails noob)

My goal is that I want users to be able to register/login with `facebook`, but I also need to authenticate requests made to my backend. (e.g. A user can only access his account info)

If I take each authenticators by itself, it works fine. For example, I can authenticate a user through facebook. And I can register and sign in on my rails server. However, I want the registration to happen through facebook( No forms to fill for the user)

The questions I have are:
- What information should I persist on my server so that I can identify a facebook authenticated user and authorize him to access ressources?
- Is there a more straight forward way to do it ?
- Does it even make sense to have 2 authentication processes ?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out this rails cast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth-revised?view=comments).
It has a good rundown of what you are looking for.

Comment: @RustComet you need to pay to watch the episode ?

Comment: Ahh. Sorry about that. I have a subscription so didn't see it. The unrevised episode is free though. [Link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth)

Comment: [In this tutorial](http://www.100percentjs.com/authentication-single-page-applications-apis-sane-stack/) they use Ember-simple-auth, and for the backend(sails) jsonwebtoken and express-jwt it's an interesting approach

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Facebook login the only data you need to persist is the App-scoped User ID (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids)

That's a unique ID generated for the user in your App. When the user logs into your App with Facebook you only have to get back this ID and then match it in your database.

I hope it helps.